# Blackberry 10 Whitelisting

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I'm using Phonegap 2.8.0 for a Blackberry 10 App.

I can't whitelist https URLs.

Other URLs are working for whitelisting.

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="https://abcdefg.com" />
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://abcdefg.com" />
```

The http is working, but the https always shows the following message:

```
Javascript Alert

Access to "https://abcdefg.com not allowed
```

Please help :-)

Answer (score 4):

For everyone else, there is a dirty solution to make it work.

In the www/config.xml add this:

```
<feature id="blackberry.app" >
    <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
</feature>
```

Not pretty, but at least you can test it with this setting

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @sunny7777777 for pointing to the workaround. For anyone else using Cordova 3.1 or higher, you can disable websecurity using this command:

`<preference name="websecurity" value="disable" gap:platform="blackberry10" />`

> @candlejack added in the comments: Set to disable to override web
>   security settings, allowing access to remote content from unknown
>   sources. This preference is intended as a development convenience
>   only, so remove it before packaging your app for distribution. For the
>   released app, all URIs should be known and whitelisted using the
>    element, described in the Domain Whitelist Guide.

I am now convinced that this workaround should only be used during development and not in production. This is true for all platforms, not just BB. So be careful to remove this before publishing your app!

Comment: WebSecurity (disable or the default enable): Set to disable to override web security settings, allowing access to remote content from unknown sources. This preference is intended as a development convenience only, so remove it before packaging your app for distribution. For the released app, all URIs should be known and whitelisted using the <access> element, described in the Domain Whitelist Guide. 
For more information: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_config.md.html